# ANDSF and OMA-DM Client/Device

Tags: android, windows, client, device, oma-dm

My training project, in a device-management-providing company, is to add a plug-in on top of the company's OMA-DM server to support the new ANDSF management object.

Now, I need to find an "ANDSF capable mobile device"(a device that supports the ANDSF feature I want to implement) so I can test my work. I found that Samsung Galaxy Note supports OMA-DM.

1. Does that mean it is an "ANDSF capable device"?  OR
2. Should I find online an ANDSF client that I download onto the Galaxy Note?  OR
3. Above two are not possible and I need to find a device that already supports OMA-DM and ANDSF functionalities?

If 2 or 3 are correct, where can I find the client/device?

Thank you for your guidance..

EDIT: Just found out that if the device doesn't have an ANDSF object in it already, there's nothing we can do/download. So does somebody know a website/something where i can know at least the name of a device that has ANDSF object built in it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need help on this ...
The answer to your first question is "No".
Just because the device is OMA-DM compliant, does not imply that it is ANDSF compliant.
In fact, given the "relative newness" of ANDSF, it is safe to say that unless explicitly stated, the device very likely will not support ANDSF functionality.

I am not sure about questino#2. Not sure how the existing OMA-DM client on Samsung Galaxy will interwork with the ANDSF client you are deploying.

Questino#3: Yes. That is what you would need to test the ANDSF server functionality.

If you found a device with ANDSF support, I would be curious to know about it.

Regards
Sunil

Comment: Thank you for the reply! 
We found some devices supporting OMA-DM and we're going to test them to see if they have an ANDSF Management Object.